# elements which are multiples of 10 are swapped

Tags: python, list, swap

The elements which are multiples of 10 are swapped with the value present in the very next position in the list.

For example If the content of list P is:

[91, 50, 54, 22, 30, 54]

Then content of list P should become:

[91, 54, 50, 22, 54, 30]

But I am getting something like:

[91, 54, 50, 54, 22, 54, 30, 54]

The non multiple of 10 element is getting reapeted.

Can someone give me a solution to it. Thanks.

NOTE: It is assumed that consecutive elements are not multiple of 10. And the last element is not a multiple of 10.

```
   l=[]
   c=[]
   n=int(input("Enter number of elements:"))
   for i in range(1,n+1):
    b=int(input("Enter element:"))
    l.append(b)
   s=len(l)
   for i in range(s): 
   if l[i] % 10 == 0: 
    c.append(l[i+1])
    c.append(l[i])
    i+=1
   else:
    c.append(l[i])
   print(c)
```

Comment: I interpreted it as: it gets swapped with its neighbour which doesn't exists and hence stays in its place.

Comment: @python_user It is assumed that the last element is not a multiple of 10.

Comment: The question is not clear - what if two adjacent numbers are all 10's multiplier - like 20, 30?

Comment: @DanielHao   It is an assignment question. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can't go forward because you would move the target elements all the way to the end. A nice trick to avoid this is to loop backwards, then it's very easy.

**Disclaimer: This doesn't work for consecutive multiples of ten as pointed out by Daniel Hao below!!**

```py
data = [91, 50, 54, 22, 30, 54]

for i in reversed(range(len(data))):
    if data[i] % 10 == 0:
        # move the item one slot to the right
        data.insert(i+1, data.pop(i))
```

Comment: what if the list is - [91, 50, 54, 22, 30, 60,70]?  The PO needs to be more specific about those "corner cases"!

Comment: @Daniel Hao Dang it, you're right, I didn't consider that. As I interpret the task, it would give the wrong result for consecutive multiples of ten.

Comment: @DanielHao It is assumed that the consecutive entries are not multiples of 10.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
l = [91, 50, 54, 22, 30, 54]
pos = 1
while pos < len(l) - 1:
    if l[pos] % 10 == 0:
        l[pos], l[pos+1] = l[pos+1], l[pos]
        pos += 2
    else:
        pos += 1
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need i += 1 under the second for-loop (for i in range (s)) because i is automatically updated in the next iteration by the loop. To solve the problem, you can check if the element exists in “c” before appending in the else block.